How to verify positive definitiveness of the given Kinetic term?
I was going through this paper on QCD chaos, where in Appendix B (page 10), for equation B12:
$$\frac{\mathcal{S}}{\mathcal{T}}= \int dt\sum _{n=0,1} \left(\dot{c}_n^2-c_n^2 \omega _n^2\right)+11.3c_0^3+21.5 c_0 c_1^2+10.7c_0 \dot{c}_0^2+3.32 c_0 \dot{c}_1^2+6.64\dot{c}_0 c_1 \dot{c}_1$$
the authors state that:

"The action (B12) describes the motion of the string in a trapping
potential with an unstable equilibrium point on its edge, as explained
above. One problem with this action is that the kinetic term of the
Hamiltonian constructed from this action is not positive definite in
some regions within the trapping potential, hence the time evolution
there is not well-posed."

My question is how to verify that kinetic term is not positive definite for some regions and why is it important?

The last terms are cubic under scaling, that is, multiplying all $c_k$ and thus also the $\dot c_k$ with the same (constant) scalar. Now consider the whole expression as polynomial in this scalar. Cubic polynomials have opposite sign towards $\pm\infty$, thus can not be positive definite.

Thank you for the explanation. Just one doubt: how does the variable change (B13) on page 10 of the referred paper rectify this issue? And what is the reason for just this form? Can't we do some other variable change as well?
